# docusign php soap error could not connect to host in APIService.php usiing https

Tags: soap, docusignapi

I am using docusign soap api using php. when I am using url https://demo.docusign.net/api/3.0/api.asmx it is working fine, Now I live API key and using https://docusign.net/api/3.0/api.asmx, it is not working, got error -  could not connect to host in APIService.php. but if i use http://docusign.net/api/3.0/api.asmx (not https) then it is working fine. Can you please tell me why we getting error when using https?

Answer (score 1):

You need the sub-domain of the production server. The HTTP to HTTPS redirect is masking your issue

ex:

```
https://na2.docusign.net/api/3.0/api.asmx
```